# How to put a space between the AppBar and TextFormField inside a card in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.teal,
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.tealAccent[700],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 600,
                width: 350,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //email
                        AppBar(
                          toolbarHeight: 30,
                          elevation: 00.0,
                          title: Text(
                            'Owner Registration ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          centerTitle: true,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        ),

                        TextFormField(
                          maxLines: 1,
                          minLines: 1,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            labelText: "Enter Email",
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                              return 'invalid email';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),

                        //password
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                          obscureText: true,
                          controller: _passwordController,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty || value.length <= 5) {
                              return 'invalid password';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),

                        //Confirm Password
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration:
                              InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value.isEmpty ||
                                value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'invalid password';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {},
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('Submit'),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          textColor: Colors.teal,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj4zr.png

Answer (score 0):

Put a `SizedBox` in between `AppBar` and `TextFormField` in `Column`.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh .. it really helps me

Answer (score 0):

Put a SizedBox (with no color or same color of background) in between AppBar and TextFormField in Column, As @Lee3 said.

or put :
`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` in your Column

Answer (score 0):

you can put `Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10)),` between the `AppBar` and `TextFromField` or as @Lee3 and @Rami Ahmed said, `SizedBox` with some height in there.

Comment: Thanks such a great help